# MCMC Modelling - can this even be solved?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, pymc

I am very new to Bayesian modelling and MCMC - I would like to know if the problem I describe below can be solved.  It seems to be there is too much missing information but I wanted to get your thoughts.  Consider the following:

I have a road intersection with one entrance and two exits, A and B.  My goal is to estimate the number of cars that pass through this intersection in a given day, which equals to the number of cars that pass through the entrance.  I post two people, one at exit A and the other at exit B, to count the number of cars coming out of their exits.  They are both not very good so they only capture `C` percent of the cars that actually pass through their respective exits.  I do not know what `C` is.  To make matters worse, the person at exit B lost his record so I only have the numbers from A.  I think this situation should be described by the following graph:

[image]

From historical data, I know on average p% of ppl go through A and (1-p)% people go through B, but on this given day, I have no information.  In this example I only have two exits, but in general I may have more (e.g. 3-5).

Is is possible to estimate the distribution for "# cars thru entrance" with the data I have?  If so, what distributions would you assign to each random variable?

Comment: By definition, $100*p$ percent of people must use A and $100*(1-p)$ percent of people must use B, unless there is a third exit, so that change in notation will simplify your graph. The same goes for number of cars thru A and B: they must add up to the total number.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll record my modelling thoughts as I create it:

```
import pymc as pm
```

How can I recreate this data? Well, `N_T` cars enter. Do I know `N_T`? No, so it's a random variable. For simplicity, I'll say its a discrete uniform with max 1000 (you can change this to, say, a Poisson)

```
N_T = pm.DiscreteUniform('N_T', 0, 1000)
```

Of these `N_T` cars that enter, I know a car will enter A with probability `p`. Thus the number of cars through A is a binomial rv. But do I know `p` for certain? Probably not, you mentioned it was a historical average, so we should model this stochastically (using the beta-binomial model):

```
p_A = pm.Beta('p_A', 50, 50) #centered at 0.5, but with some variance. This depends on your historical data.
N_A = pm.Binomial('N_A', N_T, p_A)
```

Next, only `C` percent of cars are recorded by A's observer. Let's just assume that `C` is completely accurate, i.e. there is no uncertainty about what `C` is:

```
C=0.95
```

Then the number of cars *recorded* is again a binomial, with `N_A` trials. Furthermore, suppose observer A record 20 cars.

```
obs_A = pm.Binomial('obs', N_A, C, observed=True, value = 20)
```

Let's fire the mcmc canon:

```
mcmc = pm.MCMC( [obs_A, N_A, p_A, N_T] )
mcmc.sample(10000, 5000)

from pymc.Matplot import plot as mcplot
mcplot(mcmc)
```

And I get this posterior for `N_T`:

[image]

Comment: Fun question, btw =)

Comment: Thanks for the reply and glad you found it interesting.  All I know about this topic is from your EXCELLENT Bayesian Methods for Hackers book.  I definitely need to re-read it again soon as I made a very quick pass (mainly because it was so engaging and readable) the first time.  Any plans on completing chapters X1 and X2?

Comment: Yes, but they will be in a different medium. Details soon ;)

Comment: What if I don't know the value of `C` and need to model that as a random variable as well?  It's actually quite crucial to this problem that I don't assume I know it's value.  Would I still be able to get reasonable answers?

Comment: Of course: you can make `C` a pymc stochastic variable: `C = pm.Beta('C', some_alpha, some_beta)`. The implication of doing this would be wider posteriors for `N_T`.